# Why does music keep getting erased from my iPhone?

Tags: music.app, iphone

I keep all of my music stored offline on my iPhone 6s (iOS 10.3.3). iCloud is entirely turned off. My iPhone's drive is also nowhere close to being full.

I just recently bought an album, and I'm experiencing this weird issue where the songs in this album keep getting removed and I have to re-download them.

Something that *might* be noteworthy to mention is that since I bought this album from the U.S. store, the titles were originally in English. I then converted them to their original given names by the Japanese artist (iTunes/Music app has never complained about this in the past).

[image: screenshot of songs being deleted]

> How do I get the Music app to stop deleting songs from my album?

Comment: Well, I'm not having the issue anymore for whatever reason. It just went away on its own. As a computer scientist, I have no clue how this makes sense. But, it's gone...so, yeah.